# Issue when testing Spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs, spring-test, spring-web

I need to add unit testing to my Spring project. I'm currently using spring framework within JAX-RS, but I'm unable to test it.

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.zcd2</groupId>
<artifactId>helloworldapi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My java file:

```
@Path("/external-spring-hello")
public class ExternalSpringRequestResource {

@Autowired
private GreetingService greetingService;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getHello() {
    return greetingService.getMessage();
}
```

}

And my test file is:

```
public class ExternalSpringRequestResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(ExternalSpringRequestResource.class);
}

@Override
protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(ExternalSpringRequestResource.class);
    config.packages("com.trial");
    return ServletDeploymentContext
            .forServlet(new ServletContainer(config))
            .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class)
            .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
            .build();

}

@Test
public void first() throws Exception {
    final String response = target("/external-spring-hello").request().get(String.class);

    Assert.assertEquals(response, "Hello");
}
}
```

However, I'm getting that error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:257)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer.<init>(InMemoryTestContainerFactory.java:78)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory$InMemoryTestContainer.<init>(InMemoryTestContainerFactory.java:64)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory.create(InMemoryTestContainerFactory.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:278)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:608)
```

It looks like an issue with jersey server library. How can I solve that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to run in a servlet environment. Won't work with in-memory provider. Use the grizzly one, then override `getTestContainerFactory` and return a `GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've changed my code so now I'm using GrizzlyWebTestContainer as you said, now the nullpointerexception has disappeared, however, the spring beans are not being initialized so my code is failing with a NullPointerException when using the non-initialized bean. What am I missing? Why it is not working if I have already set contextParam from ServletDeploymentContext? Thanks!